# Can I retrieve BSSID of an access point that my computer connected to through browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, bssid

The title explains it all. I'd like to retrieve bssid of an access point that my computer is connected to. I'd like to do this through java script in the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible via JS on client side.